# Save data to two different tables in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I want to post data to two Tables (Articles and Contents).

Contents belongsTo Articles (multiple Contents for one Article) and this is written in my ContentsTable.php

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('contents');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Articles', [
        'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

Now I want to post all the Contents in the table and also create one article.

ContentsController.php

```
public function add()
{
    $content = $this->Contents->newEntity();
    $id = $this->Auth->user('id');

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $contents = $this->Contents->newEntities($this->request->data());

        foreach ($contents as $content) {
            $content->article_id = $id;
            $this->Contents->save($content);
        }

    }

    $this->set(compact('content'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['content']);
}
```

I tried to do it by using `associated`, but it didn't work.

```
$content = $this->Contents->newEntity($this->request->data, [
            'associated' => ['Articles']
        ]);
```

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description! Even if the problem might be obvious for people that know the CakePHP internals, please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens, and what you'd expect to happen instead. Show the data that you are working with (the post data), the code required to reproduce the problem (all the entity/saving code, not just the `newEntity()` call), your debugging attempts (not just "workaround" attempts), and possible errors (validation errors, exceptions, etc). Often the problem solves itself when collecting such information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and Error leaded me to the solution + Reading the Docs again... and again.

**Articles Controller**

```
public function add()
    {
        $article = $this->Articles->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->data, [
                'associated' => [
                    'Contents'
                ]
            ]);
            // Added this line
            $article->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

            if ($this->Articles->save($article, array('deep' => true))) {               

            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your article.'));
        }
        $this->set('article', $article);

    }
```

**Test add.ctp in Articles**

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('contents.0.article_id');
                echo $this->Form->hidden('contents.0.type', ['value' => '1']);
                echo $this->Form->hidden('contents.0.position', ['value' => '3']);
                echo $this->Form->hidden('contents.0.text', ['value' => 'test']);

                echo $this->Form->hidden('contents.1.article_id');
                echo $this->Form->hidden('contents.1.type', ['value' => '7']);
                echo $this->Form->hidden('contents.1.position', ['value' => '7']);
                echo $this->Form->hidden('contents.1.text', ['value' => 'test7']);
```

**And added this to my ArticlesTable.php**

```
$this->hasMany('Contents');
```